# Is it true that $E[Y|W]=E[Y|E(X|W)]$, given that $W$ is $X$ measured with error

Tags: regression, expected-value, measurement-error, conditional-expectation

In Carroll's 2006 book "Measurement Error in Nonlinear Models", and on p38 it is stated without proof that:

> [One can] estimate the regression of $Y$ on $(Z, X)$ and then to substitute into this model $\{Z,E(X|W)\}$ [ ... ] [which is equivalent to] to substituting (Z, W) into the fitted model for the regression of $Y$ on $(Z,W)$.

$W$ is a measurement of the predictor $X$, but measured with error. $Z$ is a covariate measured without error.

Which is the following equivalence.

$$ E[Y|W] = E[Y|E(X|W)]$$

(I have remove $Z$ from the subsequent calculations, as they are not needed in my problem).

Is there a proof for this? I have found the following paper that mentions this, but it is vague.

> Babanezhad, Yaghmaei (2010) "Bias Terms of Measurement Error in Treatment by expected Estimating Equations"

Comment: It is clearly the case when $E[X|W]=\alpha W$.

Comment: Excuse me, but what does $\alpha$ mean in this context?

Comment: Re.: This is a coefficient. Any coefficient.

Comment: Re-reading the paragraph in the book, I wonder if the end of it could
not be ``substituting $(Z,W)$ into the fitted model for the regression of $Y$ on $(Z,X)$''. Then the
question would concern the possible quality $E(Y|W) = E[Y|X=E(X|W)]$,
which seems sensible. In this case, I would still answer: no
with a counter-example.

Comment: @Xi'an, do you have a paper (or other reference) that shows that this is clearly the case when $E[X|W]=αW$. I would like to understand this for myself (this maybe something elementary in stats, that I don't know yet).

Answer (score 2):

The relation $E[Y | W] = E[Y | E(X | W)]$
does not hold in a general context, e.g. when if $Y$ is assumed
to be independent of $W$ conditional on $X$.

Assume that $X$ is standard normal and that $W := X^2$, so that $E(X |
W) = 0$. If we take $Y = X^2 + \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is a
noise independent of $X$, then $E[Y | W] = W = X^2$, while $E[Y | E(X
| W)]$ is simply $E(Y) = 1$.

Now, I confess that in this example $W$ can not be regarded as $X$
with a measurement error, so further assumptions should be imposed.

As suggested by @X'ian, the relation would hold if we could be sure
that $E[X|W]$ is a linear function of $W$, say $\alpha W$ for some
$\alpha$. This linearity is granted for example by assuming that the
vector $[X,\,W]^\top$ has an *elliptically symmetric* distribution. In
the present context, only $\alpha =1$ would make sense.

Comment: Ok, so say for example $W$ is normally distributed with mean $X$ (aka $W \sim N(X,\sigma)$), so that $E[W]=X$, this would mean that as $W$ is symmetrically distributed around $X$, the relation would hold? Also, I am not sure why $E(X|W)=0$?

Comment: In your question the assumptions about $X$ and $W$ are not explicit
and I thought that it was about the identity in a fairly general
context, so I allowed $W := X^2$, which is *not* $X$ with error. You
might  have in mind the extra assumption that $X =W +$ error or $W
=X +$ error. See also my comment to the question: I suspect that your
interest is on the value of the regression function of $Y$ on $X$ when
$X$ is taken equal to $E(X|W)$. This is a different identity.

Comment: I understand that your first paragraph was about $W$ and $X$ in a general (non error) case. Are you saying that the identity I stated in the question $E[Y|W]=E[Y|E(X|W)]$ is incorrect, and that I should be trying to proove $E(Y|W)=E[Y|X=E(X|W)]$ instead?

Comment: No, I would not say that is is incorrect but that it could 
not really express what you want to do: susbtitute $E(X|W)$ in place of
$X$ in the regression $E(Y|X)$ of $Y$ on $X$. If $g(X):=E(Y|X)$ (say)
and $h(W):=E(X|W)$, the question would be about the relation
$E(Y|W)=g[h(W)]$. I can hardly figure out that $E[Y | E(X | W)]$ could
be known in practice, since this mixes the regression and error
models in a quite subtle way.

Comment: Ok, so to make it a bit simpler, as I want to substitute $E(X|W)$ in place of $X$, then I need to prove that $E[X|W]=\alpha W$ (where as yourself and X'ian stated, $\alpha=1$)? Then this leaves the regression on Y out of the evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

The equation
$$E[Y\mid W] = E[Y\mid E(X\mid W)]\;\;\;  \text {does not hold in general}$$

but let's see a very "well-behaved" example where it does hold. Assume that $\{Y, W\}$ follow a bivariate normal distribution, and that $\{X,W\}$ also follow a bivariate normal. For simplicity assume all three variables have zero unconditional expected values. I will use for compactness $E(X \mid W) \equiv Z$ (which is *not* the "Z" in the question). Then

$$E(Y \mid W) = \frac {{\rm Cov}(Y,W)}{\sigma^2_W} W =  \frac {E(YW)}{\sigma^2_W}W  \tag{1}$$

$$E(X \mid W) \equiv Z  = \frac {{\rm Cov}(X,W)}{\sigma^2_W} W = \frac {E(XW)}{\sigma^2_W} W\tag{2}$$

where "$\sigma$" denotes here the standard deviation. $Z$ follows a normal distribution, and being just a scaled version of $W$, it too has a joint bivariate normal distribution with $Y$. So

$$E(Y \mid Z) = \frac {{\rm Cov}(Y,Z)}{\sigma^2_Z} Z = \frac {E(YZ)}{\sigma^2_Z} Z \tag{3}$$

We are wondering "Is $(1) = (3)\;?$". For it to hold we must have

$$\text{If}\;\;\; (1) = (3) \implies \frac {E(YW)}{\sigma^2_W} W = \frac {E(YZ)}{\sigma^2_Z} Z \tag{4}$$

From $(2)$ we have

$$\sigma^2_Z = \left(\frac {E(XW)}{\sigma^2_W}\right)^2 \sigma^2_W = \frac {[E(XW)]^2}{\sigma^2_W}  \tag {5}$$

Inserting $(5)$ into $(4)$, and inserting the expression for $Z$ from $(2)$ we obtain the requirement

$$\text{If}\;\;\; (1) = (3) \implies \frac {E(YW)}{\sigma^2_W} W = \frac {E(YZ)\cdot \sigma^2_W}{[E(XW)]^2} \frac {E(XW)}{\sigma^2_W} W$$

and simplifying we arrive at

$$\text{If}\;\;\; (1) = (3) \implies \frac {E(YW)}{\sigma^2_W}  = \frac {E(YZ)}{E(XW)}   \tag{6}$$

Now, assume that $W = X+U$ where $U$ is zero-mean  normal independent of $X$ and $Y$ (this is consistent with the assumptions of pairwise bivariate normality). Then

$$ E(XW) = E(X^2) = \sigma^2_X$$

Inserting  into $(6)$, while also substituting for $Z$ (from $(2)$) we obtain

$$\text{If}\;\;\; (1) = (3) \implies \frac {E(YW)}{\sigma^2_W}  = \frac {E\left(Y\frac {E(XW)}{\sigma^2_W} W\right)}{\sigma^2_X}  $$

$$\implies  \frac {E(YW)}{\sigma^2_W}  = \frac {E(XW)}{\sigma^2_W}\frac {E\left(Y W\right)}{\sigma^2_X}$$

$$\implies 1 = \frac {E(XW)}{\sigma^2_X}$$

which holds so here indeed

$$E[Y\mid W] = E[Y\mid E(X\mid W)]$$

does hold.